# Do Global Variables actually persist in VBA for the entire Excel session

Tags: excel, vba

I've used Global variables in Excel VBA and have found that they haven't persisted throughout the session. My question is if it is because of something wrong I did, or do they not always stay for the whole Excel session?

Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: Where did you declare it? Why did you say it did not persist or retain it's value? Can you show example so we can replicate it? As far as I know, public variables or you can call it global retain its value in the whole excel session, same instance.

Comment: Globals persist as long as the VBA isn't halted (e.g. by an unhandled error)

Comment: Thank you, Tim. I believe that's the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Tim Williams answered the question.

Globals persist as long as the VBA isn't halted (e.g. by an unhandled error) –  Tim Williams

Thank you, Tim.

Answer (score 0):

You are suffering from the VBA State Loss problem

I have solved this here [In Excel VBA how to persist key variables over a 'state loss' (without writing to a cell or a file)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38952243/in-excel-vba-how-to-persist-key-variables-over-a-state-loss-without-writing-t/38952244#38952244)