# Persisting custom class objects using AppDomain in VBA

Tags: .net, vba, excel, mscorlib

Following the idea form [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38956839/2248196) I'm trying to create a universal persistent storage in Excel using VBA but am having issues with the retrieval of stored object from the storage after VBA reset.

As a simplified example let's say I want to persist an instance of custom class 'MyClass':

```
'MyClass
Public someText as String
```

A simplified version of the storage:

```
Public Sub Save()
  Dim x As MyClass: Set x = New MyClass
  x.initialized = True
  Dim domain As mscorlib.AppDomain
  Set domain = GetAppDomain()
  domain.SetData "x", x
End Sub

Public Sub Load()
  Dim y As MyClass 'alternative: Object
  Dim domain As mscorlib.AppDomain
  Set domain = GetAppDomain
  If IsObject(domain.GetData("x")) Then
    Set y = domain.GetData("x") 'Type mismatch error
  End If
  Debug.Print y.initialized 'Run-time error '-2147418105 (80010007)'
End Sub

Public Function GetAppDomain() As mscorlib.AppDomain
  Dim host As New mscoree.CorRuntimeHost
  host.Start
  Dim Unk As IUnknown
  host.GetDefaultDomain Unk
  Set GetAppDomain = Unk
End Function
```

When I run Save and Load subs consecutively I get the desired output ("true"). However if I reset the application (Run > Reset in VBE) I get a Type mismatch error.  When I change the type of `y` to `Object` I get an Automation error (Run-time error '-2147418105 (80010007)') when trying to print `y.initialized`

Originally I've tried to have a persisted Dictionary as in the link above, in that case I was able to get the Dictionary back from domain, the key was still there, but I was not able to cast the contained object back to it's original class.

Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Can you give us some more details on `MyClass`?  What is its base-class, is it serializable?  There are some restrictions about what kind of objects are allowed to cross app-domain boundaries.

Comment: Yeh, I'd imagine that a custom class will not be retrievable. Can it be stringified? <xml> can Also be put into CustomXMLParts as well...